# Auto-generated WCF proxy class renames request/response classes

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to generate a WCF proxy class for an ASMX service I want to consume.

I have tried using both 'Add Service Reference' is VS and the command line svcutil.exe to generate a proxy from the ASMX service WSDL, but each time it creates an duplicate service method (for each operation) with different request and response classes (that have the digit '1' appended to the end the names).

Does anyone know how to stop WCF creating these duplicate methods with the request/response class names having the digit '1' appended to them?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't paste in the ASMX code as it is for work and top secret. But this is what gets generated... 'code' SomeMethodResponse SomeMethod(SomeMethodRequest request) AND SomeMethodResponse1 SomeMethod(SomeMethodRequest1 request) - I don't want the latter

Comment: Unless you are able to create sample which replicates your problem you will hardly get a solution. Even MS official support would require sample to replicate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the code is top secret and I can't give it to you. Sorry - it looks as though nobody knows the answer anyway. I will close this question down soon and cry in a corner

Comment: If you can't post any code to give us an **idea** of what's going on, then yes- I'm afraid no one will be able to help you.... good luck with your *top secret* projects......

Comment: Thanks. I am a spy doing a WCF project. I likey secret projects they make me feel special and better than everyone else (including all of you)

Answer (score 0):

In your project folder you might have either of the folders 'ServiceReferences' or 'WebReferences'. Look inside these. If they have any folder of the same name as your service reference delete it. Now add the service reference again. It should work.